# Batch command to change the resolution of a computer

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, screen-resolution

I want to write a command in a batch file which changes the resolution of a computer. I am using Windows XP.

I need to set the resolution as 1024*768.

Comment: What operating system version / distro. Which monitor?

Comment: Given that the author speaks of a batch file, I assume one of the latter version of Windows. [Duplicate of this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490004/windows-batch-file-to-change-monitor-settings)

Comment: i edited the question for which operating system and what resolution i need

Answer (score 8):

I needed more options, so I developed [ChangeScreenResolution.exe](http://tools.taubenkorb.at/change-screen-resolution/) to change the screen resolution in a batch file.

Examples:

Change screen resolution of all monitors to 800x600px

```
ChangeScreenResolution.exe /w=800 /h=600
```

Change screen resolution of all monitors to 800x600px with refresh rate of 60Hz and 32bit color depth

```
ChangeScreenResolution.exe /w=800 /h=600 /f=60 /b=32
```

Set resolution of display with index 1 to 800x600px

```
ChangeScreenResolution.exe /w=800 /h=600 /d=1
```

To list all available displays (and their indexes):

```
ChangeScreenResolution.exe /l
```

Comment: The current version fails to start on Win7 due to missing MSVCP120.dll, I think that means it needs the Visual Studio 2013 redistributable package - [link](https://www.microsoft.com/de-at/download/details.aspx?id=40784)

Comment: @zrin Yes, sounds like that.

Comment: @AlexanderTaubenkorb Doesn't even launch on Win 11 22H2

Comment: @IonT I am sorry, I have no Windows 11 at the moment. I assume you have the [Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable Package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784) installed (don't know if still required in Win 11, but was in Win 10) If you have more information (if you run in cmd, maybe you see sth more, I can look further into that).

Comment: @AlexanderTaubenkorb Yeah Visual C++ 2013 is already installed on my pc. Actually i noticed that upon .exe launch a cmd window appears but then disappears shortly. Tried running it as an administrator but with no luck .

Comment: @IonT maybe the parameter `/log=log.txt` gives more insight in the log.txt file.

Answer (score 5):

You can use either of the following two tools.

1. [MultiRes](http://www.entechtaiwan.com/util/multires.shtm)
2. [QRes](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Video/Other-VIDEO-Tools/QRes.shtml)

**Using MiltiRes:**

```
multires.exe /800,600,32,75
```

**Using QRes:**

```
QRes.exe /x:800 /y:600
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer , but can you xplain multires.exe /800,600,32,75
what this command is doing???

Comment: @user2144638, The screen resolution is 800x600, in 32 bit color and 75Hz refresh rate.

Comment: Do you have MultiRes or QRes in your path?

Comment: Thanks @NextDoorEngineer

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried MultiRes, but note that Qres will only run on 32-bit machines.

[DisplayChanger II from 12noon.com](http://12noon.com/?page_id=641) also works beautifully and is free for personal use.

[DisplayChanger](http://12noon.com/?page_id=641) is designed to be called via command line or batch script, and has both 32-bit and 64-bit versions.  It can also generate editable config files specifically for multi-monitor (or projector) setups.  You manually set the displays up how you want, "create" a config for it, then call that configuration up at any time.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a script which uses the program provided by [Alexander Taubenkorb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/936284/alexander-taubenkorb) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35720103/3982001) to fix monitor black screen issue due to "screen resolution out of monitor range" caused by StarCraft not reverting my desktop resolution back to its original settings on exit.

Here's the .bat content - feel free to use it.

```
taskkill /f /IM explorer.exe

%~dp0%\Starcraft.exe

start explorer.exe

REM *change below /w=XXX & /h=XXX values that reflect your monitor's needs* 

ChangeScreenResolution.exe /w=800 /h=600 

REM *this is the minimum resolution of monitor - brings desktop back to life*

ChangeScreenResolution.exe /w=1024 /h=768

REM *this is the recommended & preferred resolution I like to run my monitor at*

exit
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use wmic desktopmonitor
[like here](https://web.archive.org/web/20061030043938/http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/qanda/jul05/hey0721.mspx)

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2005/07/21/how-can-i-determine-the-current-screen-resolution-being-used-on-a-computer/

Comment: No longer works for win2008 or newer [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394137(v=vs.85).aspx)               
Possibly use powershell instead [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/10/03/use-powershell-to-discover-multi-monitor-information/)