# Changing Screen Resolution and Scaling in one Batch file, and Launch a .exe file as well

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, vbscript, windows-11

I wanna set the screen resolution of screen 1 to a predetermined value of **1872 x 1248** then set **scaling to**  **100%** then launch a .exe file from a folder, and once the exe is closed revert the screen automatically back to **3240 x 2160 and 200% scaling.**

EDIT1:

[Batch command to change the resolution of a computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324290/batch-command-to-change-the-resolution-of-a-computer)

this one helped me set the resolution and it works fine:

```
  ChangeScreenResolution.exe /w=1872 /h=1248 /d=0

allFiles.exe

/wait allFiles.exe 
ChangeScreenResolution.exe /w=3240 /h=2160 /d=0
```

But I couldn't find any resources on how to set resolution scaling at all, that's the missing bit, I'm fairly sure it can be done, but I don't know how.

How can it be done?

Thanks

Comment: We are not here to help you with 'googling' problems! This site helps you with a specific issue with a submitted [mcve] of your code. Please make sure that you visit the linked pages of [ask] to better understand how things work on StackOverflow, then [edit] your question to include, that code properly formatted, and sufficient information for us to replicate that issue.

Comment: I figured out how to change the resolution and automatically back once the program is closed, but I can't find any resources on display sclaing, how can it be done?

Comment: We do not provide those resources for you, we are not your interactive search engine, performing your research for you, then linking you to the results.

Comment: Edited it with my findings and solution so far, thanks for the answer!

Comment: We expect you to ask one specific question about a single specific and reproducible issue with your submitted code. We are not here to bolt on the parts you've not researched and coded yourself. Please, before you make any more comments or changes, revisit the [tour], then read and understand the [ask] pages, I've already advised.

Comment: I am asking one thing and one thing only: how can I edit my code to set display scaling along with the resolution. Everything else is figured out, but I couldn't find anything about it, and as you can see I'm not well versed with .batch code in general. I can't specify the issue any more than the resolution scaling should change, but I don't know what functions or utilities to use, and don't even know if it's possible at all, that's why I'm seeking help from more knowledgeable people, who actually might have an idea how this whole stuff works. I wanna learn but I'm stuck and need help. Thanks

Comment: I couldn't find any resources to set display scaling along with resolution is not a failing code problem, it's a failing research issue. The comment section is not where you specify all of the pertinent details of your question. Please use the [edit] facility, to remove all of the unnecessary bloat, _(questions and information)_, from your submission, and include only the specific failing code issue you require us to assist you to fix. That should also include any error and debugging information, and all of the things we need to be able to validate that on our systems in a similar environment.

Comment: Edited it to the current stance of matters, thanks!
Failing research, I've spent all night trying to come up with something, but resolution scaling seems to be out of my grasp. I turned to you for help, because for someone who knows if this can be done at all, and is well versed in this kinda programming, this whole stuff might take 10 seconds, while for me not even knowing if it's possible, I can spend a lifetime on it just to realize in the end it wasn't even possible to begin with :/

Comment: Contact the developer of that application (the author of the answer you linked) and ask them if the application supports doing so. We know nothing about the application that you downloaded from a link provided in a SO answer. Your question is about support for that specific application, not a programming question, and I've voted to close it as a general computing/software question for that reason.

Comment: If it can be done in a general way I'd be happy too, but the source code is not available, and I don't even know where to begin. All the code I found online didn't work.

Comment: I have just used my preferred web search engine, and my first three results were [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1334781/is-it-possible-to-change-display-scaling-via-command-line), then [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/questions/65033/command-line-for-scaling-in-windows-settings-for-d.html), then [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1610078/is-it-possible-to-change-display-scaling-to-150-via-command-line). Are you sure that there is nothing at all in those which can help with your issue? _(perhaps not 'googling' would be the best advice I could offer you)_.

Comment: It can't be done from a batch file, which is why the author of that program wrote it (as they say in the answer where you got the link). Contact that author (via a comment on the answer) to ask if what you want is possible. **We can't support an app that we know nothing about and do not have the source code for**, and your question is about using that application.

Comment: Also, considering you said that you had everything else figured out, there is no such command as `/wait allFiles.exe`.

Comment: THanks @Compo I've been through those, but they don't seem to work, they just open the settings app and nothing happens. I can't comment on the solution I linked because I don't have 50 karma points. I wrote him an email, hope that helps.

Comment: oh it should come after the first allFiles.exe, like the other / stuff! Thanks, it worked fine before though I was lucky it didn't do anything

Comment: @haephaistoss, two of the links do have code which opens the settings pages, but they do navigate those using `vbscript` and `sendkeys`, and one of the links includes not only registry locations, but also links to a potential powershell based solution too. Frankly I cannot believe that you've fully explored all of those in such a short space of time. _(Although you must be speedy, because the time it took you to read through all of [ask] was unbelievable)_.

Comment: Thanks I found it out from one of the links you sent me, SetDPI does exactly what I need. I didn't know DPI and resolution scaling was the same thing! Thank you guys, love you all! <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So thanks to @Compo I figured out how it can be done:

https://github.com/imniko/SetDPI

https://tools.taubenkorb.at/change-screen-resolution/

And these 2 can do the trick for anyone interested:

```
::This bit changes Screen Resolution of Display1 to 1872 x 1248
::ChangeScreenResolution.exe [/w=1872 Horizontal Pixels] [/h=1248 Vertical Pixels] [/d=0 Means Display1]
ChangeScreenResolution.exe /w=1872 /h=1248 /d=0


::This bit changes this bit changes the scaling for Display1 to 125% 
:: SetDPI.exe [Display Number 1 - means Display1] [Scaling %]
SetDPI.exe 1 125

::This bit starts allFiles.exe and goes on to the next line ONLY AFTER IT'S CLOSED
allFiles.exe /wait 

::This bit sets resolution back to original
::ChangeScreenResolution.exe [/w=3240 Horizontal Pixels] [/h=2160 Vertical Pixels] [/d=0 Means Display1]
ChangeScreenResolution.exe /w=3240 /h=2160 /d=0 

::This bit sets scaling back to original
:: SetDPI.exe /[Display Number 1 - means Display1] /[Scaling %]
SetDPI.exe 1 200
```

Thanks guys, it works like a charm now!